# Should use TreeMap or HashMap for wrapping named parameters?

Tags: java, performance

In most cases, there will be only 0-5 parameters in the map. I guess TreeMap might have a smaller footprint, because it's less sparse then HashMap. But I'm not sure.

Or, maybe it's even better to write my own Map in such case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I guess TreeMap might have a smaller
>   footprint, because it's less sparse
>   then HashMap.

That may actually be wrong, because empty `HashMap` slots are `null` and thus take up little space, and `TreeMap` entries have a higher overhead than `HashMap` entries because of the child pointers and color flag.

In any case, it's only a concern if you have hundreds of thousands of such maps.

Answer (score 5):

The main difference is that `TreeMap` is a [`SortedMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), and `HashMap` is not.  If you need your map to be sorted, use a `TreeMap`, if not then use a `HashMap`.  The performance characteristics and memory usage can vary, but if you only have 0-5 entries then there will be no noticeable difference.

I would not recommend you write your own map unless you need functionality which is not available from the standard Maps, which it sounds like you don't.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need **order** of entries in `Map`, so `HashMap` is OK for you.

And 5 entries are not performance concern.

You need to write `Map` which has dozen of methods to implemented, I don't think that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If your about 5 keys are always the same (or part of a small set of keys), and you are usually querying them by string literals anyway, and you only seldom have to really parse the keys from user input or similar, then you may think about using an enum type as key type of a EnumMap. This should be even more efficient than a HashMap. The difference will only matter if you have many of these maps, though.